# IBM 4690 operating system is that linux kernel based

Tags: operating-system

My colleague working with IBM 4690 operating system told me that it's based on linux kernel. Is that true ?
Or is that Dos based ?

Comment: I don't think it's based upon either of the two.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4690_Operating_System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the latest version of the Toshiba POS system does have a Linux kernel. The Linux is leveraged to run JAVA apps. The 4690 OS is in fact DOS based and runs on top of the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

In the last couple years its changed a bit.  4690 is completely it's own operating system, was a deritive of FlexOS and CDos. In the last couple years they've started what's call "4960 Enhanced" which was built on top of the IBM MCP ( think embedded linux ).  This opened up a lot of new features.  Since Linux is running underneath ( but embedded ) there are a bit of things you can get to, but not like a straight command line.  I believe v6r3 or v6r4 started that up.  Java especially can run easily on the linux side ( java 1.6 or TDK 1.8 which is an opensdk 1.8 equivalent ) can run there.  To run much else, you need to create extensions which is another topic in itself.

They're currently working on 4690 v7, which will move to their own Linux distribution and open up a lot more things.  The main is a modern C compiler that will run on the Linux side rather than on the 4690 process.

Comment: it should be JDK 8 right where JDK 9 is still experimental in even Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Yes, it's 8.  I still use the old 1.8/1.6 representation.  I hadn't seen much on 9 yet.

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting.  I'm hoping that the thousands of installations that I'm familiar with are moving in this direction over the long term.  So from the embedded Linux, can you programmatically get access to many of the SA features, such as accessing the transaction logs (EAMTRANA, EAMTRANB, EAMTRANC), and perform an indexed lookup within the EAMITEMR file, etc?  I've tried to do research, but all I can find is bland marketing material.  Thanks in advance.  I've been dealing with the 4680/4690 operating system for nearly 26 years, and it would be nice to see it finally modernize.

Comment: How old is your latest Programming Guide?  It has some of the Java stuff in there, but it just doesn't give many details.  The same Java calls you can do in 1.4 works in 6 and 8.  There's some extra classes for doing things on "4690" files instead of Linux for example, but I think at least the classes and functions are available in there, just not a lot of other details.  I don't think there are any Java classes specially made to read the tlogs, so you'd have to implement a parser.  Keyed files it does just fine, and it can handle the distribution(always a big on in 4690) as well.

Comment: @Brent Shores: thanks a lot - I really appreciate the information.  My Programming Guide is ancient, and doesn't cover that.  I'll have to ask one of our customers for some new documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.  It's a multitasking version of DOS created by Digital Research, and extended by IBM.  Back in the 90's we had hoped that they would switch to a more modern OS, but they never did.  Even their flagship product IBM ACE / SurePos ACE uses multitasking DOS - to this very day.  It's a very limited OS, but serves its purpose.  BTW, there's no swap file - when you run out of memory, it crashes.  It's the craziest OS I've ever developed for.  Good luck finding a C compiler for it - the only place you can find one is on Ebay.

Answer (score 0):

IBM 4690 runs on its own Kernel and not UNIX based. Its commonly used for Point of sale retails systems. The popular OS version is V6R5 from Toshiba and the major applications are GSA (General Sales Application), SA (Supermarket Application) and ACE.